# Reduce white space between top of page and Chapter, Bibliography and Appendix head titles in report class?

Tags: bibliographies, chapters, appendix, white-space

Due to default setting of report class, there is white space between top of page and TOC, LOT, LOF, Chapter, Bibliography and Appendix head titles and I wish to reduce this space. I successfully figured out reducing this space for TOC, LOT and LOF using

```
% reduce white space before toc, lof, lot
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-1em}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-1em}
```

But I am trying to figure out the same for Chapter, Bibliography and and Appendix

Here is a complete MWE for reducing space for TOC

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}   % added <<<<

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-5em}  % added <<<<

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Conclusions}

\appendix

\chapter{Formulas}

\end{document}
```

[image: reduced white space before TOC]

Compare to output using MWE below without using the above added modifications:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Conclusions}

\appendix

\chapter{Formulas}

\end{document}
```

[image: default white space before toc]

for brevity, I am not showing output for Bibliography but it is the same amount of white space that I need to reduce

[image: default white space before chap]
[image: default white space before appendix]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `titlesec` package to adjust the space before the chapter title with the command

```
\titlespacing{\chapter}{<space left>}{<space before>}{<space after>}
```

`\titlespacing` does not work with  `\chapter`  unless you change its title format as well, by means of `\titleformat`.

To emulate the default values use

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}   % added <<<<

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-2.0ex}  % added <<<<

%***************************************% added <<<<
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}% emulate the default values
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-4.5ex}{*3.5}
%***************************************

\usepackage{showframe}% ONLY to  show the margins

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Intro}
    
    Some text.
    
    \chapter{Test}
    \chapter{Conclusions}
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Formulas}
    
\end{document}
```